# NoClassDefFoundError spring boot maven

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, dependencies, noclassdeffounderror

Im programming a REST API with spring boot which uses some external libraries which are included via dependency in my pom.xml. 
If i start the project in IntelliJ via **mvn spring-boot:run** everything works just fine but if i try to package everything into a jar via **mvn package** all external dependecy calsses are missing except the ones of spring-boot. However, the corresponding jarfiles are copied into the lib folder of the jar. 
So if i Start the jar everything works just fine (answering for getRequests etc.) But as soon as i want to initialize a variable of type ***FFmpegFrameGrabber*** (which is from bytedeco) i get a ***NoClassDefFoundError***

My POM looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>spring-boot-test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
            <artifactId>javacv</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The structure of the genrerated jar (part of it):
jar 
  + hello 
  + lib 
  + META-INF 
  + org 
  ----+ springframework 
  ----+ HERE shoould be bytedeco (?)

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Minimal (Not) working example

```
package hello;

import org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        String path = "D:\\TestVideos\\1\\original.mp4";
        FFmpegFrameGrabber frameGrabber;
        System.out.println("Starting Frame Grabber for: "  + path);
        frameGrabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(path);
        try {
            frameGrabber.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "Greetings from Spring Boot! Opening: " + path;
    }

}
```

And the Application.java

```
package hello;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

        System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");

        String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        Arrays.sort(beanNames);
        for (String beanName : beanNames) {
            System.out.println(beanName);
        }
    }

}
```

This is straight from the spring boot tutorial.
tanks again

Comment: I'm not familiar with bytedeco, but its jar should also be in your jar's `lib` folder and all of its classes should be available. Perhaps it does something unusual? Can you provide a small sample that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Its the hava wrapper for ffmpeg. All ffmpeg jars are in the libfolder, but no classfiles in the appropriate places.

Answer (score 0):

Add the plugin below  in your `pom.xml` `<build><plugins> ... </plugins></build>` section. 
 Build the maven project and execute the jar command.
 This plugin will package all your dependent jars into the final executable jar.

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

This page has more information on maven assembly plugin - https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html

Comment: This does not work becaause it kinda messes up the paths for spring boot. Normally, the spring-boot:repackage adjusts these names in the jar generated by maven (if i am correct). Therfore i would need to call spring-boot:repackage on the jar with dependencies. Any ideas? The error when starting the jar with dependecies: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedde
d container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextE
xception: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedS
ervletContainerFactory bean.

Comment: ok. Did you try [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html)